# SQL query issue in Inner join

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have tables `Creditcard`, `Childcreditcard1`, `Childcreditcard2`

Childcreditcard1

```
CreditcardID  TranscationDatetime
22222132132   2010-04-11 12:36:10.210
22222132134   2011-04-11 12:36:10.210
12364132122   2019-04-11 12:36:10.210
45677132124   2011-04-11 12:36:10.210
45677132124   2012-04-11 12:36:10.210
```

Childcreditcard2

```
CreditcardID  TranscationDatetime
22222132132   2010-04-11 12:36:10.210
22222732134   2011-04-11 12:36:10.210
12364132192   2019-04-11 12:36:10.210
```

MasterCreditcard

```
CreditcardID            primaryCreditID
22222132132     22222132132             
22222132134     22222132132             
12364132122     12364132122         
45677132124     45677132124
45677232124     45677232124     
78567723212     78567723212 
23677232124     23677232124 
45678944343     45678944343
22222732134     22222732134
12364132192              12364132192
```

Now from these three tables I need to get the `creditcardID` which did not match only   from `MasterCreditcard` whatever `CreditcardID` we have in `Childcreditcard1`, `Childcreditcard2` tables will always be there in `MasterCreditcard` table

Result should be  table  should like this

```
 45677232124
 78567723212
 23677232124
 45678944343
```

My query:

```
select 
      distinct(cc.CreditcardID) 
from 
      MasterCreditcard  CC  
inner JOIN 
      Childcreditcard1 c1 ON CC.CreditcardID <> c1.CreditcardID 
inner JOIN 
      Childcreditcard2 c2 ON CC.CreditcardID <> c2.CreditcardID
```

I tried like this but this gives result of all `CreditcardID` in `MasterCreditcard` table  which is wrong

Comment: is the answer help full to you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this might work for you

```
select distinct(cc.CreditcardID) from MasterCreditcard  CC  
left JOIN Childcreditcard1 c1 ON CC.CreditcardID =c1.CreditcardID  
left JOIN Childcreditcard2 c2 ON CC.CreditcardID =c2.CreditcardID   
where c1.CreditcardID  is null or c2.CreditcardID   is null
```

my answer is based on this image, second image left outerjoin case

[image]

Comment: @happysmile - can say waht is that ?

Comment: select distinct(cc.CreditcardID) from MasterCreditcard  CC   left outer JOIN Childcreditcard1 c1 ON CC.CreditcardID =c1.CreditcardID   left outer JOIN Childcreditcard2 c2 ON CC.CreditcardID =c2.CreditcardID    where c1.CreditcardID  is null andc2.CreditcardID   is null